# Difference between datepicker and datepicker dialog?

Tags: android, datepicker, datepickerdialog

Simple and clear, I  just want to know if there any difference between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One is a *control* that you add to **your** dialogues or windows the other is a *dialogue* in its own right you should be able to tell from the naming which is which!